# Decode XML into interface type with Go?

Tags: xml, interface, go, decode

Is it possible to decode XML into an interface type with Go 1.3?

For example, if the structs look something like this (simplified):

```go
type Field interface { ... }

// DataField and ControlField satisfy Field interface
type DataField struct { ... } // <- One concrete type, with XML tags
type ControlField struct { ... } // <- Another concrete type, with XML tags


type Record struct {
    Fields []Field // <- Field is an interface
}

...
// we want to decode into a record, e.g.
var record Record
decoder.DecodeElement(&record, &se)
...
```

As far as I can see, it is possible to decode XML with the concrete types, e.g.:

```go
type Record struct {
    ControlFields []ControlField // <- Using concrete type works
    DataFields []DataField // <- Using concrete type works
}
```

But the interface type fails, although the implementations are annotated with the correct XML tags.

For a runnable example, see http://play.golang.org/p/tPlw4Y74tt or as [gist](https://gist.github.com/miku/8f1b8c91d7028f1ad3f5).

Answer (score 1):

From looking at [the code](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/xml/read.go#L345) in the `encoding/xml` package, it seems, interface types are just skipped:

```
...

switch v := val; v.Kind() {

case reflect.Interface:
    // TODO: For now, simply ignore the field. In the near
    //       future we may choose to unmarshal the start
    //       element on it, if not nil.
    return p.Skip()

...
```

Go version: 1.3.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the comment here. You can't unmarshal into an interface, because there's no way to generate the proper concrete type at runtime. If you never reference the concrete type directly, they won't even be compiled into final binary. JSON for example throws an error in this case, but it seems they've left the possibility open for an interface to swallow a start element in xml.

Comment: here's an example of controlled unmarshaling into an interface with JSON (I'm not as familiar with the XML api, but I assume something similar could be done there) http://play.golang.org/p/-MBRu1W5p9

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that given some interface and some concrete types implementing it, the information needed to unmarshal into the "right" type was there.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks for your example, I guess, this is what I had in mind how it could work, using struct tags as type hints.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the values inside your interface arrays with some concrete type or xml will not be able to infer to which type are you referring to:

http://play.golang.org/p/6LVgK7rza9

```
            // InterfaceRecord fails
            record := InterfaceRecord{
                Fields: []Field{&DataField{}},
            }

            decoder.DecodeElement(&record, &se)
            output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(record, "  ", "    ")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
            }

            os.Stdout.Write(output)
```

Output:

```
  <record>
      <d tag=""></d>
  </record>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. It seems your solution would work, if I knew in advance the number of fields in the record, which I - unfortunately - do not. As I [understand the stdlib](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/xml/read.go#L345), XML cannot be unmarshalled into an interface type, yet.